# iOS vector images (PDF) displaying issue

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, vector-graphics

I stuck with a strange iOS vector image issue - i've got an image in pdf format as a vector graphics.

All was good during Xcode local dev builds, but suddenly build from Xcode Cloud show me next:
some part of an images disappeared in every image use occurrence

[image]
Here is first iteration of issue

After some time playing around with vector image options - i've got this

[image]

A little bit better, but still no luck to fix everything.
And one more strange thing - image displays correctly if it size > or < than default 1x size from pdf file.

But this is not an issue for all vector images (see 4 and 5)

And there is Xcode local build result
[image]

Have no idea why it working this way (especially having all working as expected even in Xcode Cloud build few iterations before).